# How do I install Qt 4.7.0 on Snow Leopard?

Tags: qt4, installation, qt-creator

I tried using the binary installer and I get the same problem I am describing below.

I have compiled it from source and used the instructions given on the Qt website, but I can't get Qt Creator to find Qt.
I tried copying the Qt directory from /usr/local/Trolltech to /Developer/Applications/QT
I have tried copying the frameworks into /Developer/Library/Frameworks

When I run Qt Creator I get the following error:

dyld: Library not loaded: QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
  Referenced from: /Developer/Examples/Qt/richtext/calendar-build-desktop/calendar.app/Contents/MacOS/calendar
  Reason: Incompatible library version: calendar requires version 4.7.0 or later, but QtGui provides version 4.5.0

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Where is Qt Creator looking for the frameworks?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I thought I deleted the question because I was able to solve the problem on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an old version of QT4 installed.

When you run `qmake -version` in the terminal, what do you get?

Here is my output:

```
$ qmake -version
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.7.0 in /Library/Frameworks
```

Comment: Before doing anything I ran the uninstall-qt.py script. I did this to clean things up. Then I used the binary installer, which didn't work. Then I moved onto compiling it myself.

Comment: I solved the problem by complete removing any trace of Qt from my system with the uninstaller scripts. Then I compiled it and ran the `make -jl install` command which put it in the `/user/local/` folder.

After doing that I installed the QtCreator binary in my `Applications` folder. I opened it up and set the location of the Qt to `/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.0/bin/qmake`. After I did this things started working.

What I don't understand is why the installer package didn't work.
I don't mind having Qt hanging out in its own special folder, but I would like to put it in my /Library/frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check QtCreator preferences to define de qt version to be used. Probably you are pointing to an old version of qt installed.
Go to Preferences -> Qt4 and then you will be able to define which version of Qt should be used.

Comment: He didn't clearly say that. Also, the shadow build path indicates that QtCreator is running, but fails to build or start his app, resp. Please ensure to call "Run qmake" and "Rebuild project" in the Build-Menu to set all the paths in the build script to the new Qt Version!